# Direct CloudFront to Specific Bucket Folder if Path Elements Exists

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution in front of a S3 static website.

I want all traffic where first path element is `profile` to be directed to one file in my bucket.

For example, for a `GET` request to `https://example.com/profile/12345`, I want CloudFront to return S3 object `s3://<bucket_name>/profile/index.html`.

My goal is that I would handle dynamic content for `profile/12345` using frontend JS and my API.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using querystrings to pass the `12345` data.

Comment: I think this can be achieved using 2 ways, the easiest way is lambda@edge to check URL contains/starts with /profile/ , change the path as profile/index.html or have the Error page configured as /profile/index.html so if /profile/12345 doesn't exist in bucket, the error page /profile/index.html will be served.